# Why is my xlsxwriter conditional formatting not working?

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have two columns in a dataframe named FirstName and LastName.

I need to make the font color of any cell's text in the FirstName column red if any cell in the LastName is **not** blank.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fileName, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1', index_label=None, index=False)
workbook  = writer.book
redFont   = workbook.add_format({'font_color': '#9C0006'})
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet.conditional_format(1, 0, 9999999, 0,
                             {'type':     'formula',
                              'criteria': '=ISBLANK($B1)',
                              'format':   redFont})
writer.save()
```

I do not get errors but the font color does not change.  I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of small errors in the code: the range is bigger than the maximum range allowed by Excel (so XlsxWriter rejects the conditional format) and also if the range starts in cell `A2` you should apply the conditional format using the reference cell `$B2`. Also I think the logic should be reversed to match cells that are not blank

It should be something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

fileName = 'test.xlsx'

df = pd.DataFrame({'FirstName': ['Anna', 'Bob', 'Cian', 'Dora'],
                   'LastName':  ['Aran', '',    '',     'Dodd']})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fileName, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index_label=None, index=False)

workbook = writer.book
redFont = workbook.add_format({'font_color': '#9C0006'})
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

worksheet.conditional_format(1, 0, 1048575, 0,
                             {'type':     'formula',
                              'criteria': '=ISBLANK($B2)=FALSE',
                              'format':   redFont})
writer.save()
```

**Output**:

[image]